# Why Find methods are absent in Enumerable<> while present in List<>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

I think my question says it all. Why Find methods are absent in `Enumerable<>` while present in `List<>`. If they were there it would have reduced the burden of writing large `LINQ` Queries to find something from `Enumerable<>`. I know i can change the Enumerable to List using `.ToList()` but that would be a hack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<TSource> Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) does exactly the same as the [List<T>.Find Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx).

> **Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<TSource> Method**
>
> Returns the **first element** of the sequence that satisfies a **condition** or a **default value** if no such element is found.
>
> *Return Value:* default(TSource) if source is empty or if no element passes the test specified by predicate; otherwise, the first element in source that passes the test specified by predicate.

> **List<T>.Find Method**
>
> Searches for an element that matches the **conditions** defined by the specified predicate, and returns the **first occurrence** within the entire List<T>.
>
> *Return Value:* The first element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, if found; otherwise, the **default value** for type T.

Comment: Only difference is that FirstOrDefault uses 'foreach' were as Find uses 'for' because it has an indexer.

Answer (score 0):

It's very common for classes to include more "helper functions" than interfaces, for the simple reason that adding a helper function to a class simply entails adding code the code for that method to one place (the class in question), while adding a helper function to an interface compels every implementation of that interface to add code for that function.

It would be helpful if the next version of the CLR could provide a means by which interfaces could specify default implementations for their members, especially if implementations of old versions of an interface could be regarded as implementing new versions, using the default implementation for any new members.  If such a thing were legal, `IEnumerable<T>` could add a `Count` method, which could be overridden by any implementation which was able to determine the number of items without having to iterate through them, but which would otherwise use a default method that would count via iteration.  If such a feature existed, adding members like `Find` to `IEnumerable<T>` would be useful.  Unfortunately, I know of no plan to implement such a feature.